# Accessing elasticsearch docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image

I am new to docker, and now I am stuck with a problem. I have a elastic search container with data injected in it. I also have flask application which I have dockerized, but Iam not able to connect my flask container with the elastic search container. I have tried all the options I could find / understood, but still not able to fix the issue.

Below is a sample of my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.2
    container_name: intelligent_lovelace
    environment:
      discovery.type: single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - my_app

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - my_app

networks:
  my_app:
```

By providing elasticsearch like this, creates a new elasticsearch instance. I will grateful if someone could point out what Iam doing wrong here..!!

Comment: Can you show us the `code` that you are using to connect to the elastic search. Are you trying with `localhost`? As on a container context the `localhost` means the container itself. You  have to try with the `container name` or the `host address`.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC Iam connecting to elasticsearch using localhost and 9200 as port number. should I remove the elasticsearch from my docker compose file services and provide container name to connect to elasticsearch?
This is my elastic connection configuration
``` host: intelligent_lovelace
  username:
  password:
  index: document
  port: 9200
  pre: http ```

Comment: You have to keep the elasticsearch in your docker compose , instead of `localhost` try the `container name` to connect in your app with elasticsearch. Like I mentioned, the `localhost` means the container itself.

Comment: (You can also delete all of the `container_name:` and `networks:` options in the entire file, Compose provides reasonable defaults for these and you don't need to specify them yourself.)